# Flutter - Make Phone Call without UrlLauncher

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-phone-call

I'm building an application using flutter and I want to be able to integrate with the phone to make calls.

In android I believe I'd ask for the REQUEST_PHONE_CALL permission.

Using flutter, I found the [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/call_number) plugin. Unfortunately it doesn't support iOS and the android implementation is still rather buggy.

The only alternative I found to achieve this is to use [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher), but that doesn't quite have the same functionality, so I want to find other alternatives.

Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to write it in the native code. I mean the code to call a number using platform channels

[https://flutter.io/platform-channels/][1]

I didn't test this and didn't try it. when I do I will update my answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that! I also got a tip to alter the UrlLauncher plugin to accept something like "telprompt" in addition to the "tel", which will do what I want. I know Ionic has a similar lib that accepts that with the functionality I want. I'll see if I can do that and post an update here.

Comment: @TiagoAlves Any luck with this?